How do I access a field value of an entity in Uniface?
How do I access a field value of an entity in Uniface?
I am trying to access the field 'NAME' of the entity 'ORDER' in the following way:
ORDER.NAME

I get the following warning after compiling in the Uniface IDE:
warning: 1000 - Field 'ORDER.NAME' not found


You have to use the field name first and then the entity name.
NAME.ORDER

